# Undefined variable in laravel 5.2 don't know why

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5

I want to display the content saved on the database on my view page. I've applied relationship between user and account.

I have another relationship between user and post which is working perfectly.

The error I am getting is:

> ErrorException in 0401a2c6f4dbf412d9f16ba1e4ced9e54c8bb622.php line 132:
>   Undefined variable: accounts (View: E:\wamp\www\gal\resources\views\myplace.blade.php)

my view code:

```
<form action="{{route('account')}}" id="acc" method="post">
  <div class="col-lg-3"><label>Estado</label>
  @foreach($accounts as $account)
  <textarea  style="display:none;" name="textfield4" id="textfield4">{{$account->estado}}</textarea></div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 es" id="estado"></div>
  @endforeach
```

my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use App\Account;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function account(Request $request)
    {
        $account = new Account();
        $account->estado = $request['textfield4'];
        $request->user()->accounts()->save($account);

        return redirect()->route('myplace');
    }

    public function getaccount()
    {
        User::find(Auth::id())->accounts;
        $accounts = Account::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();

        return view('myplace',['accounts'=>$accounts]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code seems OK. Delete the cache and try again.

Comment: @itachi sry but doesn't work...any other possible solution?

Comment: What about your $accounts variable, is really defined? try to dump the result before call the view

Comment: @Mirdrack yep it is defined

Comment: Please put the code in the question. If/when the links break in the future, this question will be of no value to anyone.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Check my answer, his problem was related to his routing table not any of his controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this code...

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use App\Account;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function account(Request $request)
    {
        $account = new Account();
        $account->estado = $request['textfield4'];
        $request->user()->accounts()->save($account);

        return redirect()->route('myplace');
    }


    public function getaccount()

    {
        User::find(Auth::id())->accounts;
        $accounts = Account::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();

        return view('myplace',['accounts'=>$accounts]);
    }
}
```

`$account->estado = $request['textfield4'];` should be `$account->estado = $request->input('textfield4', 'some_default_value');`

`User::find(Auth::id())->accounts;` does literally nothing as you don't save the result, and `$accounts = Account::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();` is sorting all accounts.

As for how none of your Accounts are being shown with orderBy is probably due to not having any query about what to select or conditions for it to be true. Default values may help, but if you have something funky it may be broken. There isn't much we can do without more code.

Another guess I have about this is `return view('myplace',['accounts'=>$accounts]);` should be `return view()->make('myplace',['accounts'=>$accounts]);`

EDIT:

His problem was he was navigating to /myplace which doesn't route to getaccount() it routes to getmyplace(), which didn't have the $accounts variable passed.

Comment: it doesn't worked........I can provide you more code.Jz tell me ....do you want full view code?

Comment: It's not a problem with the view it's a problem with probably how you're handling routing, middleware, or Model. You can confirm if you were to `dd($accounts)` right before the view is generated that the variable is defined and has values that look correct?

Comment: I followed the same procedure for my posts and it worked ..so why not for this BTW i did dd($account) and gt this : 

Account {#183 ▼
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:5 [▶]
  #original: array:5 [▶]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true}

Comment: Alright then, your getaccount() function isn't the problem then. At some point you must build the view 'myplace' and just haven't noticed where yet.

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: Try to follow your routes and see every function of yours that it goes through. Look at your browser, find the route, go to routes.php and see where it goes. Follow the trail.

Comment: here are my routes: Route::post('/account',[

'uses' => 'AccountController@account',
'as' => 'account'


 ]);

Route::get('/es','AccountController@getaccount');

Comment: So when you go to the url <domain>/es it fails?

Comment: yes, actually when i use $account in my view , no url works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118342/discussion-between-sieabah-and-yash-chaudhary).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
return view('myplace',['accounts'=>$accounts]);
```

You can use compact in your Controller:

```
return view('myplace')->with(compact('accounts'));
```

Comment: In that case if you are hitting the public function account in your controller take into consideration that you are making a redirect to the route('myplace') without setting the "accounts" variable

Comment: The problem seems to be on the logic of your views/controller but try checking if the $accounts variable exists enclosing the whole foreach loop with this: @if($accounts) ..... @endif

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118333/discussion-between-jose-garrido-and-yash-chaudhary).